# Inserting element in XML under a sequence in an order specified by schema

Tags: java, xml, dom

We have a large workflow of programs that parse data into XML files. We have about 14 schemes each having a different root and is made up of about 60 XSD files. Some of the schemes share similar elements but the schemes are currently being modified on weekly basis.

I have a stage (written in Java) that accepts an XML file (which might correspond to any of the 14 schemes) and reads a list of tuples of (xpaths, message) and for each xpath a flag element is inserted under the element defined by the xpath that contains the message.

```
<default:flag issueDateTime="2012-01-10T21:00:09" recipient="lablabla" resolvedIndicator="false" sender="SS" xmlns:default="default">
  <default:flagSubject/>
  <default:message>
    <default:p>This element should be non empty</default:p>
  </default:message>
</default:flag>
```

My current approach was to insert the flag element as the last child of node referenced by the xpath, that has been casing an issue. In some schemes the referenced node does accept the flag element under a sequence in an order defined by the xsd (could be middle, first or last) so adding it as last element renders the xml invalid when the element already has subelements from that sequence.

My question is, how to append an element under a sequence in a way that respects XSD defined order?

I'm currently doing this

```
Element flag = rawXmlDoc.createElementNS("default", "default:flag");
xpath = factory.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(nsContext);
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathText);
Element refNode = (Element)expr.evaluate(rawXmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
if (refNode.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    refNode.appendChild(flag);
else 
    refNode.getParentNode().appendChild(flag);
```

I am hoping to get an answer using the standard DOM interface without relying on MOXy.

Comment: We had this same problem (well basically after inserting a bunch of elements in various xmls we needed to sort the into proper schema defined order, with complex schemas including other schemas etc). Long story short, I ended up coding a program which parsed schema trees using DOM parser and then used that information to sort elements in sequences in other XMLs which use these schemas.

Comment: @UMad thanks for your comment, I'm surprised Java DOM API does not offer this. Would you consider sharing your code?

Comment: Sorry. I don't own the rights to code I make, customers who paid for it do. Basic idea is that XSD is also an XML, which makes it possible to process it with dom parser. It is possible to resolve all includes and namespaces.

Comment: @Meitham How did you solve this? I'm facing very similar issue

Comment: @Learner JAXB approach was rejected by the client and ended up altering their schema to avoid the issue. Unfortunately that means we didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use JAXB? When you use JAXB along with XJC, you can

- generate Java classes from your XSD files
- use JAXB to unmarshal the XML into Java objects
- manipulate the XML with Java
- use JAXB again to unmarshal the Java objects into valid XML

That's using standard Java XML API's but not directly DOM. However, JAXB is contained in every JDK, so you have no additional dependencies

Comment: We can't use JAXB because it means we have to compile the schemes into classes every time they change. I looked into MOXy which can dynamically compiles the schemes for me so I don't need to create a new jar every time the schema changes, but unfortunately I found it to be fragile and unstable. I have a feeling this could be done using the standard DOM API but I just cannot see how.

Comment: You can use JAXB without source code generation, but I have no experience with that... Maybe someone has a better solution